# Why is the algorithmic complexity of this code 1/2n^2 + n + 1?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

For the following code:

```
  print a

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = i; j < n; j++)
      print b
```

Obviously, the big oh of n for print a is just 1, but I don't understand how the second part is 1/2n + 1/2n^2.

The first for loop represents n and then the second for loop represents (1/2 + 1/2n) I guess?

Answer (score 3):

The outer loop runs `n` times.

The inside loop runs `n, n-1, n-2, ..., 1` times.

The complexity of the code inside the loop is `O(1)` so the total complexity is:

`n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = n(n+1)/2 = (1/2)n^2 + (1/2)n = (n^2)/2 + n/2 = O(n^2)`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote, but thank you good sir/madame

Answer (score 0):

For `i = 0`, `print` will be executed `n` times.

For `i = 1`, `print` will be executed `n-1` times.

For `i = 2`, `print` will be executed `n-2` times.

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

For `i = n - 1`, `print` will be executed `1` time.

Summing up, `print` will be executed `n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1` times.

Thus, the complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loops, the total number of time that the print statement is called can be calculated by

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1
```

which sums to `n(n+1)/2`. So the big O notation for this complexity should be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with discrete mathematics, going step-by-step using Sigma notation would let you see the sought result as such:

[image]